# Composer Environment variable missing on CodeDeploy Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, composer-php, aws-code-deploy

I'm integrating **AWS Auto Scaling Group** with **Code Deploy**.

I wrote a bash script for AfterInstall hook.

The script executes **composer update**, **composer dump-autoload** since my code is using PHP.

**And here is the problem.
When I deploy, deployment fails with this log.**

> [RuntimeException]
>
> The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly

But when I get to instance via SSH and run composer it works fine.

**How do I fix this?** Anyone had worked around this issue?

Any answer will be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem using [Elastic Beanstalk](http://amazon.com/Beanstalk) and i did fixed it adding an [Environment variable](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html)

[image]

[image]

You should be able to achieve this in [CodeDeploy](https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/devops/using-codedeploy-environment-variables/) too for example on creating the application.

[image]

See also https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4789

Comment: @jesuisgenial you are welcome :) remember to set me as answerer if fixed :)

Note: i added one more screenshot

Comment: Thanks it worked! And I found a easier way and it's just running composer with ENV variables.. like this COMPOSER_HOME=$COMPOSER_HOME composer install --no-interaction --no-dev --optimize-autoloader

Comment: Oh great! Glad that helped :D :D :D

Answer (score 1):

Could you make sure the env variable is also accessible by the user you specify in the appspec file to which runs the hook script? If you have multiple user running on the instance, env variable might not be accessible to every user depends how you set it up.

Comment: Oh I didn't even know I could specify which user to run hook scripts. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same concern regarding composer install using CodeDeploy. It runs well in develop but when I ran it in production, I'm getting:
[stderr] [RuntimeException]
[stderr] The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly
I SSH to instance and run composer and I get:

```
user@server:~/httpdocs$ /opt/plesk/php/7.2/bin/php /usr/lib/plesk-9.0/composer.phar install
```

Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files
user@server:~/httpdocs$

I have one ec2 instance and I deploy in 2 separate directories for stg and prod.
[codedeploy deployment error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyfWU.jpg)